# Clean up lines from log file

Tags: vbscript

I have a file "D:\test.log" that has either one of two styles. This will appear if the user is offline when the user received the message:

> [02:19:47] Brother Aimbot (adama900): (Saved Thu Mar 31 05:15:09 2016)This is a test line

It will be like this if the user is online when the user received the message:

> [02:19:47] Brother Aimbot (adama900): This is a test line

What I would like this to do is cut out the excess parts so it would look like this if it's either the first or second style:

> Brother Aimbot (adama900) This is a test line

then place it into a message box.

Here is my code:

```
Sub main()
  filename = "D:\Test.txt"
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename)
  LNEVAL = f.ReadLine
  LNENUM = 0

  Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
    For i = 1 To LNENUMs
      f.ReadLine
    Next

    If InStr(LNEVAL, "(S") Then
      LNEVAL = Left(LNEVAL, (Len("(S")+4))
      MsgBox = LNEVAL
    End If
  Loop

  f.Close
End Sub
```

This is what I have so far.

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly simple to do what you want with a [regular expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wzad2b2%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) replacement. Basically what you want to do is remove three things from each line:

- a substring between square brackets from the beginning of the string,
- the colon separating the name from the message, and
- an optional substring between parentheses after that colon.

A regular expression `^\[.*?\]` matches an opening square bracket at the beginning of a string and the shortest number of characters up to a closing square bracket.

A regular expression `\(Saved.*?\)` matches an opening parenthesis followed by the word `Saved` and the shortest number of characters up to a closing parenthesis. However, since this part is optional you need to indicate that the expression can occur zero or one time by putting it in a non-capturing group and appending the `?` modifier to it (`(?:...)?`).

Put the submatches that you do want to preserve in parentheses to create capturing groups

```
^\[.*?\] (.*?): (?:\(Saved.*?\))?(.*)
```

and [replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9z80300%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) each matching line with just the captured groups:

```vb
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = ...

Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename)
Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
  MsgBox re.Replace(f.ReadLine, "$1 $2")
Loop
f.Close
```

---

Some comments on your existing code:

- `For i = 1 To LNENUMs`: this loop is always skipped over, because you set `LNEUMs` to 0. Since you only do `f.ReadLine` inside that `For` loop your outer `Do` loop becomes an infinite loop, since you never read the file to the end.
- `Len("(S")+4` always evaluates to 6, because the length of the string `(S` is not going to change, so you could just replace the expression with the numeric value.
- `MsgBox = LNEVAL`: The [`MsgBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfw6660x%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) function doesn't work that way. Remove the `=` between function name and message.